# allowing ACCESS-CONTROL-ALLOW-ORIGIN on wampserver

Tags: html, cors, wampserver

i'm trying to access a distant website from my local website in wampserver.
I found that i should activate the CORS using :

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
</IfModule>
```

but should this code be added in the source website (the one i created in local) or in the destination website (the one i'm trying to access) ?

thnx a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The site hosting the HTML document in which the JavaScript runs has to be given permission **by the other site** in order to read data from it (or to send preflighted requests to it).

Comment: oh oky so what i understand is that the 2 lines should be in the distant site not my site (as my site is the one containing the JavaScript code).

Comment: Yes. A website can't give itself permission to use its visitors' browsers to read data from other sites. That would make the security restriction useless.